# How to remove the number on the tab of an Accordion?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, accordion

Accordion can be downloaded here - http://www.javaswingcomponents.com/product/accordion

[image: accordion sample]

Here is a sample output of an accordion. I want to remove the numbers on the right side of the tab. How can I do it? Thanks!

Here is the code of the sample:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import com.javaswingcomponents.accordion.JSCAccordion;
import com.javaswingcomponents.accordion.TabOrientation;

public class SampleAccordion extends JPanel {
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SampleAccordion codeExample = new SampleAccordion();
                frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
                panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                panel.add(codeExample, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(500, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public SampleAccordion() {
        JSCAccordion accordion = new JSCAccordion();
        JPanel transparentPanel = new JPanel();
        transparentPanel.setOpaque(false);
        transparentPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        JPanel opaquePanel = new JPanel();
        opaquePanel.setOpaque(true);
        opaquePanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        accordion.addTab("Tab 1", new JLabel("help me remove 1"));
        accordion.addTab("Tab 2", new JLabel("help me remove 2"));

        accordion.setTabOrientation(TabOrientation.VERTICAL);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 30, 30));
        add(accordion);
    }

}
```

Comment: You might be better off asking the folks at the link you referenced how to do this

Comment: support was ended years ago =(

Comment: Then I guess you will need to read the API to see what methods are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can specify whether you want to see the tab index:

```
accordion.setTabOrientation(TabOrientation.VERTICAL);
((FormattedTabRenderer) accordion.getTabRenderer()).setShowIndex(false);
```

(The first line is already in the sample code and is only included as a reference.)

It looks like the accordion supports three pluggable look & feels: basic, steel, and dark steel. I'm not sure whether the tab renderer can be cast to the `FormattedTabRenderer` abstract class for all PLAFs, but it seems to work fine for steel.